# Connection Error with docker postgres using network=host

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-desktop

## Problem

I'm unable to connect to a PostgreSQL database (14.1/latest) running in a docker image on my laptop.
I'm trying to connect to the database both with .NET EntityFrameworkCore/Npgsql running in another container on the laptop, and with `psql` running directly on the laptop.

### Environment

- MacOS 10.15.7
- Docker Desktop 4.3.2 (72729)

## Recreate

I start my postgres container like so. Note that since it's in host network mode, I don't publish ports.

```sh
docker run -d --network=host --name=my-database -v dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres postgres
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS      NAMES
18e154fe815c   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes   5432/tcp   my-database
```

Logs from the `my-database` container show

```
...
2022-01-11 16:56:18.179 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-01-11 16:56:18.179 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-01-11 16:56:18.179 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-01-11 16:56:18.182 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-01-11 16:56:18.188 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-01-11 16:35:54 UTC
2022-01-11 16:56:18.203 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

At this point I expect to be able to connect to the database, but I get an error.

```sh
$ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Comment: have you allowed local host in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: @SantoshKaranam i have not done anything like that. I really don't think I need to, since I have gotten this working before with the same image. Again, I have done no additional configuration of the database image beyond what you see.

Comment: I never use network=host but my guess is you would still need to publish the port using for instance `-p 5432:5432`

Comment: have to logged into the container with
"docker container exec -it 18e154fe815c cmd"
before you ran the 
"psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres"

Comment: @Chai Then you'd be wrong

Comment: @Chai, Hans Kilian is correct. In fact combining the two flags gives a warning that published ports are discarded.
Satosh Karanam, I'm now certain that there is no need to log in to the container or modify anything in it, as I have successfully made the connection. I'll post my "resolution". I do appreciate the effort, of course

Comment: great, I learned something here. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I really can't say I understand what's happened here, but after trying a number of combinations of flags, this is what allows me to connect as I expect

```
docker run -d --rm -p5432:5432 --name=my-datbase -v dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres postgres
```

Obviously this is a different strategy than I proposed above, since it eliminates the `--network=host` param, and instead publishes its port.

Now, as the comment on this answer suggests, this does not necessarily resolve another, related case, which is how to connect to this database from *another* container.

To make this work, I had to create a docker network, i.e.

```
docker network create my-network
```

and the add the flag `--network=my-network` to *each* of the containers: the `my-database` container and the application container that needs to connect to the database. Now both of these containers are on the same virtual network.

Finally, *from the application container* I can run (for example) `psql -h my-database -p 5432 -U postgres` . The hostname is the name of the docker container, i.e. `docker run --name=my-database ...`

That is, the two containers must be on the same `docker` network. It appears that, contrary to my initial instincts, the default `bridge` network does not work this way, so a custom one is required.

`docker network ls` and `docker network inspect my-network` will be useful to others debugging similar situations.

Much of this could be simplified using `docker-compose` but that was not a viable option in my particular case.

Comment: it is directly mapping port 5432 on host to port 5432 on the container, if that is the behavior you want to go with, but using name connection like `my-database` is preferred when you are connecting from another container, in environment variables you would use the container name instead of localhost

Comment: @M-Raw indeed, this is the case, and thanks for pointing it out. In this case, I am developing a local developer workflow, and the particulars are tedious, but involve connection from VisualStudio. In the production version, k8s is where such connection information is handled (And that works great).