# Postgres container does not accept connections when run host mode

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-network

I am trying to run Postgres in a container.

When I start the container using the following command wherein I map the port 5432 of my machine with that of the container, the Postgres accepts connections from another process and everything works as intended.

```
docker run --name postgres --rm -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
```

`netstat`-ing the port also works well i.e

```
nc -z localhost 5432
Connection to localhost port 5432 [tcp/postgresql] succeeded!
```

Now if I use the host mode to run the postgres container, it stops accepting connections. Basically the following doesn't work:

```
docker run --name postgres --rm -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust --net=host -d postgres
```

I saw a similar question on StackOverflow but it doesn't explain why things don't work. Here is the link to that question:
[Connection Error with docker postgres using network=host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70671610/connection-error-with-docker-postgres-using-network-host)

Any ideas why the second command doesn't work are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/9be26c49de0613992eac60ba5567d6da)

Comment: `--net host` is almost never necessary.  Since you have a working setup with the correct `docker run -p` option, can you just use that?  When you say "it doesn't work", what does happen?

Comment: @DavidMaze Agreed. I can simply use the docker run -p option. However, it is really troubling me that I cannot use the host network.

Also when I say it doesn't work, I mean I am unable to connect to postgres from the process I am trying to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't aware of the fact that host networking is not supported on mac.

A snippet from https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

```
The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.
```

Another related SO question:
[How to tell docker on mac to use host network for all purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859635/how-to-tell-docker-on-mac-to-use-host-network-for-all-purpose)